# What is the preferred way to go from a non-decimal basis to a decimal basis?

Tags: number-bases

We can insert a number in a basis different than 10 using the `basis^^number` expression.
However, strangely enough, there does not seem to be a corresponding functional form to do this.
Moreover, to convert a number of inputs to decimal basis, the common syntax

```
2^^ # & /@ {0, 11, 10, 0}
```

does not work, and I have to use instead an expression of the form

```
ToExpression["2^^" <> ToString@#] & /@ {0, 11, 10, 0}
```

This, however, seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Why does the former syntax not work? And why is there no functional form of the `basis^^number` short syntax?

Comment: `BaseForm` is the functional form and appears to work with `Map` in the way you've described above.

Comment: Are you aware of `FromDigits[#,2]&`  :   `FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}`gives : `{0, 3, 2, 0}`  ?

Comment: @IPoiler `BaseForm`, to my knowledge, only converts *from* decimal to another basis. How do you make it work the other way around, without using the `base^^number` syntax?

Comment: @glS Isn't that what he's trying to do? If you have a number that's already in another base that you want converted to decimal then you just `BaseForm[#,10]`. For example, `BaseForm[2^^10,10]` gives `2`.

Comment: @andre I was aware of `FromDigits`, but I didn't notice before the possibility of using as in `FromDigits["ff",16]`. This of course allows to use it with `Map` with something like, for example, `FromDigits[#,16]&/@{"aa","ff"}`, which is way better than using `ToExpression`. Thanks a lot for the pointer, I'll accept that as an answer if you care to make it such (I still wonder on why exactly is there no functional `FullForm` for the `base^^number` syntax though)

Comment: @IPoiler `BaseForm[#,10]&` does nothing at all, as you can easily try. Show me how would you convert a list of binary (or hexadecimal, or whatever else really) numbers to base 10 with the `BaseForm` notation and I will be convinced!

Comment: andre gave the solution (`FromDigits`).  The reverse is not `BaseForm` but `IntegerDigits`. `^^ # &` does not work because  `^^` is not an operator but part of the number syntax, just like the decimal point is, or `*^` for the exponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better solution than your workwaround :

```
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ {"0", "11", "10", "0"}
```

or :

```
FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ ToString /@ {0, 11, 10, 0}
```

> {0, 3, 2, 0}